# Showing an image in actual size with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, browser

I want to show an image in actual size(real world size). I used `mm` unit to show the image in  actual size but it wasn't exact in my two computers. 
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDFPW/) of my code, this is a picture of a credit card. a credit card is 85.60 × 53.98 mm so if you put your credit card on screen you probably will see it's smaller.

```
img{
    width:85.60mm;
    height:53.98mm;
}
```

Basically the problem is `mm`, `cm` and `in` units are not working properly in screen. They are fine in printed version. Actually it seems those units are not made to work in the screen as what I got from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths).

So is there any solution for this problem?

-----EDIT------

I created another fiddle that you can resize the credit card. The question could be how can I find that "Ratio" number? Please look at [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDFPW/2/) and let me know what you thinking? Is there any way to find that Ratio number from user agent string or something?

Comment: What do you mean by "real world size"?

Comment: I mean it should be exactly in size of a real credit card. just compare it with your credit card

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. If you know the dimensions of what you want, where's the problem? Why don't you compute the card dimensions to pixels for instance?

Comment: Do you use any server side language or javascript ?

Comment: @yoda it does make sense. The real problem is mm and cm or in units are not working properly. if you define  width:1cm you will NOT get an element with 1cm width on SCREEN.
@ Omeid it's all in browser. just CSS.

Comment: Yoda...the OP is referring to resolution independent rendering of real world physical dimensions--something that doesn't quite exist right now.

Comment: Have you reseted those markup elements with CSS?

Comment: @DA that's why the question doesn't make sense, but there's always something we can do to make it look as real as possible.

Comment: @yoda It does make sense. Did you ever saw an ad in newspaper that show "actual size" of the product? Like a cell phone.

Comment: @Mohsen .. ok, it seems I'm not being understood. Maybe I was wrongly thinking that as common knowledge between coders, and skipped to the part where you actually try to at least make it similar. Anyway you already have your answer, if doing the best you can doesn't fit I guess there's nothing you can do.

Comment: The question certainly makes sense, but, yes, to anyone that understands the medium, the answer is a very definite "no, you can't"

Comment: Thanks @yoda and DA. I updated my question. Please take a look at the new fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mm and cm should not be dependant on pixels. But for it to render properly your browser has to combine screen diameter, aspect ratio and resolution.

W3C only recommends mm for print so there is probably a large difference in browser implementation for screen

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units

BTW on my 1920x1080 (16:9) screen it works quite well

Comment: You asked if there was a solution. The answer is no. That's your answer. :/

Comment: Ah sorry, that was my eloborate way of saying "No you can't"

Comment: you can find the ratio but not the screen size (22" 25" etc)

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this until operating systems, graphics cards, and display manufacturers all agree on a universal standard for converting physical dimensions into a pixels applicable to the particular set up a user is using.

The term for this concept is [Resolution Independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_independence)

While there is some support for this in OSX and Windows, it's by no means complete and still takes manual intervention to set up properly.

On top of all of that, you are at the mercy of the end-user deciding to over-ride your measurements using zoom--be it on the desktop such as in Firefox or on a touch device by pinching.

So, at this point, I'm afraid there's no way to go about it.

Comment: All I'm getting is Nos! Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, that *is* the answer. "No, there is no solution to this at this time". Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that mm and cm are dependent on pixels, and pixels vary from monitor to monitor. Adjust your screen resolution and you'll see what I mean.

So, I guess the answer is a 'no'. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I feel it's a big no but this is what I have to deal with! :)